# preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\\'

Tags: php, preg-replace, ipb

This is likely the simplest issue ever. But I did not write the code and its not commented. I am just trying to fix it because its causing a lot of issues on my site. Its in the main text parser code.

Error: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'
More Complete error:  PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\' in .../cutout/text/parser.php on line 1192, referer: domain/forums/

Code: http://pastebin.com/k98mpF8n
There is a lot of it so this is the simplest way to do it. $text is the parameter. Looks like its a bad word filter but seems to be missing with lots of things. I can't find out what is being passed sorry. Unless you know of a why that I could.

```
-
$text = preg_replace( '/(^|\W)' . preg_quote( $test ) . '(\W|$)/i', "\\1" . $replace . "\\2", $text );
-
```

I am sure I am just missing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is your question that thing you mention in the title? I cannot find any other question. Please put the main question in the body.

Comment: Updating it. Sorry for not added the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace(): Unknown modifier` occurs when `$test` contains a `/`.

```
preg_quote( $test );
```

should be

```
preg_quote( $test, '/' );
```

`/` is the PCRE delimiter used in your `'/(^|\W)...(\W|$)/i'` expression.

PHP PCRE's can have any delimiter, so you have to tell `preg_quote()` which delimiter is used.
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php